# Hibernate - A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance when add @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I have these two associated entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Schedule> schedules = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schedule")
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

When i hard update the schedules like this

```
@Transactional
public Long updateCourseSchedule(Course course, Set<Schedule> schedules) {
    course.setSchedules(schedules);
    courseRepo.save(course);
    return course.getId();
}
```

it throws exception

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.mfa.lms.courseoffering.model.Course.schedules; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.mfa.lms.course.model.Course.schedules

But when i remove the @Transactional annotation it works. I wonder how that makes the difference?

I tried to google it but doesn't help much